# How to access the location permission using button in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, location

The design has two buttons. One button is to access the location and other is to skip. There is no dialog box while accessing the location. Can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add Permission in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

And in your activity on button click listener ask for permission like this,

```
class Sample: AppCompatActivity(R.layout.sample) {

    private var locationPermissions = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.sample_button)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            if (checkPermissions()) {
                // code if permission granted already
                // else request permission
            } else {
                requestPermissions()
            }
        }
    }

    // check for permission
    private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

        // If we want background location on Android 10.0 and higher, use:
        // ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    // request for permissions
    private fun requestPermissions() {
        permissionRequest.launch(locationPermissions)
    }

    // Permission result
    private val permissionRequest = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        val granted = permissions.entries.all {
            it.value == true
        }
        permissions.entries.forEach {
            Log.e("LOG_TAG", "${it.key} = ${it.value}")
        }

        if (granted) {
            // your code if permission granted
        } else {
            // your code if permission denied
        }
    }
}
```